# pass textbox string to custom control in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

Im using wpf and I want to pass a paramter of some textbox.text string on button click from my main window to my user control contained in my appPages folder, how can I achieve this?

The app control I want to send it to is called FindCurrentStudent, I dont like asking for direct code but I cant really find anything on this?

The way I was thinking was something like:

```
    private void btnGeneral_Click(string _value, object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string value = textBox1.Text;
        AppPages.FindCurrentStudent v1 = new AppPages.FindCurrentStudent(value);
        //does not contain a constructor?
        value = _value;
```

And then from the customcontrol I could call it like so:

```
string MainWindowValue = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve this. Depending on your current design, you might:

- bind `Button.Command` to a command exposed by your `UserControl`, and `Button.CommandParameter` to the `TextBox.Text`
- bind a property exposed by your `UserControl` to `TextBox.Text`
- bind to properties on your view model(s)

You'll need to give more information on your current design before I could helpfully elaborate.